# WindowsForms WebBrowser plugin white list

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

I need to create white-list of plugins that are allowed to run inside WebBrowser control.
I managed to implement IInternetSecurityManager and to allow / disallow all plugins that are installed. Unfortunately I can't get CLSID or something else of plugin that is about to load inside website (for example Flash in youtube.com)

Does anyone know is this possible? Can I get a list of plugins that are about to run?

Basically I want to allow Flash to run only on if I run it on a trusted site.

Of course, I can do this by HTML manipulation on DocumentCompleted event, but there is major drawback to this aproach. Someone could load plugin by JavaScript after initial load. Also while I receive this event, sync it's async, plugin is already running until I handle it from code.

Thanks